# Three.js – how to resize canvas without resizing renderer or scaling contents?

Tags: javascript, canvas, three.js, resize

I'm making a website with a Three.js canvas that fills the viewport. I'd like it to remain visually unchanged when resizing the window, ie. no scaling at all.

Currently here's what I'm doing:

- `renderer.setSize(window.screen.width, window.screen.height)`
- Then, on init and resize:

  - `camera.fov = window.innerHeight / window.screen.height;`
  - `camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;`
  - `renderer.setViewport(0, 0, window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);`

This works, but I'm concerned that maybe it's inefficient, since the renderer size is the same whether the browser is in full screen or just a tiny window. Does `setViewport` successfully limit the calculations needed for each frame or is everything basically still calculated and then cropped?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One answer to this can be found in the official documentation, I couldn't see it at first because it's [hidden in the FAQs](https://threejs.org/docs/#manual/introduction/FAQ):

```
visible_height = 2 * Math.tan( ( Math.PI / 180 ) * camera.fov / 2 ) * distance_from_camera;
```

Here's an adapted version (do this on resize – or rather, save the window dimensions and use the saved values in a throttled function):

```
renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
camera.fov = Math.atan(window.innerHeight / 2 / camera.position.z) * 2 * THREE.Math.RAD2DEG;
camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
```

Also important not to forget `camera.updateProjectionMatrix();`!